# Unable to change the language in kali

Tags: kali-linux, language

I tried changing the language in settings of Kali, but it didn't bring out options of other language to select from. And because of this, I'm unable to use the terminal. 
My question is **How do I change the language in Kali when it doesn't bring out any option of languages to select from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And because of this, I'm unable to use the terminal.

If you can use the terminal a little, input `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: was able to use the recovery mode to reset it, thank you